# ignore tweepy log messages

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging, tweepy

I'm newbie with [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) and I'm trying to find a way to ignore  [`tweepy`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v3.5.0/index.html) log messages. For example these debug messages generated from [`API.get_user`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v3.5.0/api.html#user-methods) method:

```
Tue, 13 Mar 2018 07:44:41 DEBUG    Signature: sdfsdf958zEptbJ0M=
Tue, 13 Mar 2018 07:44:41 DEBUG    Updated url: https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?id=740903288871096320
Tue, 13 Mar 2018 07:44:41 DEBUG    Updated headers: {u'Host': u'api.twitter.com', u'Authorization': u'OAuth oauth_nonce="3453453451520941481", oauth_timestamp="1520941481", oauth_version="1.0", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_consumer_key="sdfsdfsdfsdfISm8r8ELDvUqNlDn", oauth_token="sdfsdf496-eFyAJ3YTiMein8G0UTsrrN90YynrXl4", oauth_signature="sdfsdfsdfEptbJ0M%3D"'}
```

Some unsuccessfull tries to get tweepy logger:

```
logging.getLogger('tweepy.bind.bind_api').setLevel(logging.ERROR)
logging.getLogger('tweepy').setLevel(logging.ERROR)
logging.getLogger('tweepy.bind').setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```

Have you any idea how to catch these log messages?

Comment: What errors are you getting? Have you tried catching them with try/except?

Comment: i'm not getting any error. I'm talking about log messages

Comment: Have you enabled debug for tweepy? it should be disabled by default